# SQL Server - CDC - Log-Scan Process failed to construct a replicated command from log sequence number (LSN)

Tags: sql-server, change-data-capture

CDC is enabled on the database and multiple tables are included for cdc. We had been receiving the below alert intermittently, monthly once which is causing the changes not written on the CT tables. We do not have option rather than just reset the transaction log using below :-

*EXEC sp_repldone @xactid = NULL, @xact_segno = NULL, @numtrans = 0, @time = 0, @reset = 1; EXEC sp_replflush;*

Error :-

```
'The Log-Scan Process failed to construct a replicated command from log sequence number (LSN) {000af057:003bd8ef:0002}
Log Scan process failed in processing log records. Refer to previous errors in the current session to identify the cause and correct any associated problems.
The Log-Scan Process failed to construct a replicated command from log sequence number (LSN) {000af057:003bd8ef:0002}. Back up the publication database and contact Customer Support Services.'
```

Let us know if you are facing this in your environment. What can be the proactive fix for this, reactive fix is causing the data loss to the subscriber(Debezium) consume the data and ending up backfilling the data

Find the current version we are running on :-

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-OD) (KB5006943) - 13.0.6404.1 (X64)